# Is there a way to keep an Amazon Fire TV from going into Power Saving Mode?

Tags: power-options, amazon-fire-tv

Asking here because it was originally posted to Super User where it was closed due to the mod considering it an Android device.

My fire department recently purchased a TV with the intention of using it to monitor things like calls, call responses and weather. For obvious reasons, this TV needs to stay on 24/7/365 (aside from things like updates or temporary power drops).

Now for the problem, this is an Insignia model ns-55f301NA22 and is an Amazon Fire TV (not using a FireStick, it is a Fire TV). From research I have done on Amazon forums, this TV cannot be kept on 24/7. Apparently while you can shut the screensaver off, eventually the TV will go into a power saving or shutdown mode. Does anyone have suggestions on preventing this TV from going into power saving mode?

We would really like the screen to stay awake at all times, but if absolutely necessary, we would be willing to have it set to come on with motion activation or something of the like.

Edit to add: our call information is sourced from a website which can run through the TV’s browser. The website does have graphics that rotate through a couple different screens.

Comment: TVs usually have some power saving/screen burn in prevention mode which supersedes any built in OS. You may want to explain where is the source of your signal for "call responses and weather" info. If it s a static website or desktop you may still run into the same problems as the TV detects no change in display signal and goes to sleep.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I edited to add a couple details. I don’t know if these are what you were looking for.

Comment: On Android phones/tablets, there's usually "Stay awake (screen will never sleep while charging)" on the Developer options. However, I don't know if there's such a setting on Fire TV.

Answer (score 1):

So, after some experimentation, we were unable to find a way to just keep the TV awake. However, we were able to connect the TV with an HDMI cable to a computer. This still caused both the TV and computer to fall asleep. However, with some setting adjustments on the computer, keeping the computer hooked up to a power source and adding a mouse/courser jiggling app, neither the TV nor the computer falls asleep.

Thank you to everyone who added helpful comments as well, you got those of us working on this issue starting to point in the right direction.